# How do I expand a data variable along a time dimension using xarray?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a DataSet `ds_object` that looks like this:

```
ds_object
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 14392)
Coordinates:
* time       (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-08-28T00:00:02.14...
Data variables:
variable  .......
```

Where "variable" is:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'variable' ()>
array(0., dtype=float32)
Attributes:
   units:      count
```

I am trying to expand the zero-dimensional `variable` by time. So essentially, change 'variable' from a 0D to a 1D array, in the shape `(1, 14392)`. `variable` would then have the same length as 'time', but with the singular value of `variable` repeated `14392` times.

I was able to do this:

```
variable = np.full((1,len(time)),variable)
```

Which gives `variable` the shape I need, but this goes back into ds_object as a coordinate variable for some reason:

```
ds_object = ds_object.assign(variable_new=(variable[0]))
print(ds_object)

<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions: (time: 13164, variable_new: 13164)
Coordinates:
  * time                  (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-08-28T00:00:02.14...
  * variable_new          (variable_new) float32 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0
Data variables: (12/28)
```

Why does this happen? How do I get variable_new added to `ds_object` as a new data variable?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! This looks like a great question, but I can't seem to run your code and get the same results. Can you make sure the code in your question is a [mre]?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dummy dataset similar to yours:

```py
In [2]: ds = xr.Dataset(
   ...:     {'variable': ((), 0)},
   ...:     coords={'time': pd.date_range('2021-08-28', periods=1000, freq='D')},
   ...: )

In [3]: ds
Out[3]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (time: 1000)
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-08-28 2021-08-29 ... 2024-05-23
Data variables:
    variable  int64 0

In [4]: ds['variable']
Out[4]:
<xarray.DataArray 'variable' ()>
array(0)
```

We can use [`xr.DataArray.expand_dims`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.expand_dims.html) to broadcast the array into a new dimension:

```py
In [11]: ds['variable'] = ds['variable'].expand_dims(time=ds.time)

In [12]: ds
Out[12]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:   (time: 1000)
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-08-28 2021-08-29 ... 2024-05-23
Data variables:
    variable  (time) int64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Alternatively, you should also be able to do this assignment with [`xr.Dataset.assign`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.assign.html):

```py
In [16]: ds = ds.assign(variable=ds['variable'].expand_dims(time=ds.time))
```